# Are there hotkeys for Everwing?

Tags: everwing

It would be useful if there was some sort of hotkey for the other actions, but I haven't managed to find it.

The three things that I could see needing hotkeys are:

1. The laser you can purchase at the start of a game
2. The time slowdown you can purchase at the start of a game
3. Jade's charge ability

Are there hotkeys for these actions? It's nearly pointless getting them as it is since I almost always die when I have to stop to activate the ability.

Note: this is for the pc version of the game.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not a hotkey, I have discovered that you can activate Jade's charge power by double clicking.

Double clicking can similarly be used to activate the lasers and I'm assuming that the time slow down is the same. I'm not sure what happens if you have more than one available at a time.

Answer (score -2):

When you have both laser and time slow, if you double press, the laser will take precedence.